# Ti.Network.createHTTPClient SSL

Tags: tidesdk

When I try to connect my application to my apache sslv3 server tidesdk reports: "SSL connect error"

```
var url = 'https://www.sipmeeting.com/';
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e) {
        //request complete do something with data
        //assuming that we are not working with XML
        alert('Response received '+this.responseText);
    },
    onerror: function(e) {
        //error received, do something
    }
});
client.open('GET',url,true);
client.send();
```

Is tidesdk sslv3 compatible?  Other sites open fine like https://mail.google.com/mail

Thank you for the help!

--John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone was on the edge of there seat I solved this.  The issue was on my apache server I needed to set ServerName in my apache ssl vhost to the same as my common name on my SSL Certificate.

To debug I turned on ssl debugging:

```
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_engine.log
LogLevel debug
```

Nothing showed up in the logs when I would type

```
curl https://www.sipmeeting.com
```

but curl would return:

```
server:~ john$ curl -v https://www.sipmeeting.com
* About to connect() to www.sipmeeting.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 208.126.100.54...
* connected
* Connected to www.sipmeeting.com (208.126.100.54) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)
```

But when I added the -3 to the curl command: I.E.

```
curl -v -3 https://www.sipmeeting.com
```

Everything showed.  I then deduced something wasn't correlating between the two certificates, and the CN was the most probable.  I changed the CN and it was fixed for both curl and tidesdk.

Thanks!

--John